# Dynamic columns in bootstrap row using CSS

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I would like to divide the bootstrap row into different colors based on the value I am passing. I want to pass in percentages. Lets say my percentages are 30,40,20, 10, my div should appear in green, red, yellow, purple in the same percentages.

My percentages are dynamic and will get changed. How can I do this?

Code is very simple

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="twenty"></div>    
<div class="forty"></div>  
<div class="ten"></div>  
<div class="thirty"></div> 
</div>
```

I am passing class value using Angular 2 component

Comment: what do you mean "value I am passing"? Can you give us an example of your markup?

Comment: share your code to help you better

Answer (score 0):

Give them id's

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="your_class" id="first_row"></div>
 <div class="your_class" id="second_row"></div>
</div>
```

And then just write in css what you want

```
#first_row {
  ... !important; /* in some cases */
}
```